# c file is not generated from tsmarty2c.php command

Tags: php, internationalization, smarty, gettext

I am using smarty gettext plugin to internationalize smarty templates on windows.
But when I run the command tsmarty2c.php c file is created but the strings are not in the file.C file is empty.

I am using PHP 5.2.9 and smarty gettext plug in version is v 1.1.Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It prints C code on stdout.

You have to use it like that:

```
./tsmarty2c.php «template_file» > smarty.c
```

Comment: I am using the cmd and in the folder which has tsmarty2c.php.
SO i am giving command as "tsmarty2c.php C:\wamp\www\smarty\templates\index.tpl > index.c". So the file is created in the directory but it is empty.

Comment: you have PHP CLI associated with .php extension?

Comment: You need to install PHP CLI to execute tsmarty2c.php

Comment: I am now able to generate the C file and the PO,MO file. But smarty is not picking from the MO files. But string in php files are getting translated.Am I missing something.

Comment: Procedure I followed is Generate C file,PO and MO files.code is as below
$language_code = 'de_AT'; 
putenv("LANG=$language_code");
setlocale(LC_ALL, $language_code); 
$domain = 'index'; 
bindtextdomain($domain, './locale');
textdomain($domain);
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain,'UTF-8');